# 1С Битрикс (ASPRO). ЧПУ для каждого торгового предложения

Tags: битрикс, чпу

Почему то у 1С Битрикс не предусмотрен из коробки ЧПУ для каждого торгового предложения.

**Задача:** превратить URL типа `plintus/7-nakladki-nalichniki/molding_pvkh_8_2_mm/?oid=8695`  в URL типа `plintus/7-nakladki-nalichniki/molding_pvkh_8_2_mm/8695/`

Возможно сработают какие то редиректы в htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Все есть, вот статья из документации: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=10233

Comment: Это не работает для торговых предложений, к сожалению.